# не стартует сервис docker

Tags: docker

при запуске выдает ошибки:

```
Dec 17 11:36:28 localhost docker[12511]: time="2018-12-17T11:36:28.401584603+03:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"devicemapper\" failed: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed"
Dec 17 11:36:28 localhost docker[12511]: time="2018-12-17T11:36:28.402109192+03:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed"
```

система Debian 9 (stretch), чего не хватает и за что цеплятся?

Comment: Вот небольшая подсказка которую нашел, но обратите внимание что что в результате могут быть утеряны некоторые image, их придется догрузить или пересобрать
    
https://log.rowanto.com/broken-docker-in-debian-jessie/